# python sqlite3 trying to compare 2 datetime value

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

im trying to do a tempmute for my discord bot but when i try to compare actual datetime and expiration_date datetime, it doesnt work because of time error.

code:

```
def check_if_tempmute_over(self,guild_id,user_id):
        cursor = self.con.cursor()
        query = f"SELECT expiration_date FROM tempmute WHERE guild_id = {guild_id} AND user_id = {user_id};"
        cursor.execute(query)
        resultat = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        self.con.commit()
        if resultat[0][0] < datetime.datetime.utcnow():
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

error

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'check_for_unmute'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\mattm\Desktop\botdiscord\MMR6\main.py", line 536, in check_for_unmute
    if database_handler.check_if_tempmute_over(guild.id,member.id) == True:
  File "c:\Users\mattm\Desktop\botdiscord\MMR6\Databasehandler.py", line 501, in check_if_tempmute_over
    if resultat[0][0] <datetime.datetime.utcnow():
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

it's looks like the value i get from the database is not a datetime value, the data type of my expiration_date column is datetime so i dont understand, if someone can help.

Comment: There is no datetime data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Even if you used it in the CREATE TABLE statement it is simply ignored by SQLite. Probably you store the dates as text like '2022-04-20', so what you get is a string.

Answer (score 0):

As "forpas" already mentioned, you can't compare a string to a datetime-object. What you should do instead is first create a datetime object of the string at `resultat[0][0]`.
But firstly, to compare two datetime objects you have to bring them into the same format, p.ex:
`print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())` returns:

> 2022-04-20 18:54:28.391162

So if the string you stored at `resultat[0][0]` is in the same format as `print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())`, you are fine and you can start to create a [datetime object](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime)(refer to Example 9) out of the String.

If not and you only want to compare dates, without hours/minutes/seconds/ms, you have to use the [.strftime-method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime).

```
datestr = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datestr = datestr.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
print(datestr)
```

> 04-20-2022

But remember, `datestr` is of type string and you still need to convert it in order to compare it to a datetime-object.
Hope this helped, let me now if you have any other question.